# How filter user with which user have null profile image?

Tags: laravel-5.8

Already my filter working with this code

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $users = (new User)->newQuery();

    if ($request->has('gender'))
        $users->where('gender', $request->gender);

    if ($request->has('fromAge') && $request->has('toAge'))
        $users->whereBetween('age', [$request->fromAge, $request->toAge]);

          if ($request->has('country'))
        $users->where('country', $request->country);

    return [$users->get()];
}
```

Now only users with a profile picture need to filter. How change this code for my requirement?

Please note that :- The existing filter should work with the new filter.  For users who don't have a profile picture I want to remove them from the members page.

Profile picture db column name is `profile_image`

Answer (score 0):

You can check `null` column with `whereNull` and `whereNotNull` in **Laravel**. In your case you can append with new filter like this:

```
...

if ($request->has('userWithProfilePicture')) {
    $users->whereNotNull('profile_image');
}

...
```

Comment: not showing error member page shows null profile picture have users

Comment: Can you dump the sql string by doing `dd($users->->toSql());`?